# How can i convert the loop code into the list-comprehention?

Tags: python-3.x, list, list-comprehension

How can I perform List Comprehension on following Code.

```
records = []
for _ in range(int(input("Enter Range:"))):
    name = input('Enter Name')
    score = float(input('Enter Score'))
    records.append([name, score])
 print(records)
```

Comment: Why would you want to? Even if possible it would be completely unreadable.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, not a big deal, just follow the logic:

```
records = [[input('Enter Name: '), 
            float(input('Enter Score: '))] 
           for _ in range(int(input("Enter Range: ")))]
```

However, conceptually, this expression is horrible.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly translate your existing code into a list comprehension:

```
records = [[input('Enter Name'), float(input('Enter Score'))]
           for _ in range(int(input('Enter Range')))]
print(records)
```

While that works, it's very confusing since the `input` at the end actually runs first, before the two input statements on the preceding line (which run once per iteration of the `range`). I'd not choose to write it this way, the code you already have is much easier to understand.

An interesting variation on your question might be how to do a list comprehension where you want the *second* input to be first in the inner 2-lists. That's actually kind of difficult to do, since we can only use expressions, not statements, to control the order the `input` calls get made in. I'd probably use an assignment expression (aka the "walrus operator", `:=`) to bind the name input to a variable, then throw away the value with some logical operators before building the inner list with the name after the score:

```
records = [(name := input('Enter Name')) and False or [float(input('Enter Score')), name]
           for _ in range(int(input('Enter Range')))]
```

There are probably other ways to do this, maybe some are cleverer than my `and False or` trickery.